# Ternary Conditions in React Components className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling data from a json file and trying to add a class only when a specific condition is met:

```
    render: function() {
    var gameList = this.props.data.map(function(game) {
        return (
            <li key={game.id} className="list-group-item">
                    {game.home_team_name}
                    <span className="pull-right {game.home.score} > {game.away.score} ? 'highlight':'' ">{game.home.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.away_team_name}
                    <span className="pull-right {game.home.score} > {game.away.score} ? 'highlight':'' ">{game.away.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.status.status}
            </li>   
        );
    });
```

This method seems to only add whatever is there into the class and not the "highlight" class if the condition is met.

Also is it possible to define a variable again inside the .map method to reduce repetition?

I've tried 
`var homeScore = {game.home.score}` but, with no luck

Comment: React used to come with an addon called `classSet`, they deprecated it and favored the use of the [classname package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classname). Maybe an overkill if you are only using it there but might come in handy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the whole ternary statement together into brackets :

```
{parseInt(game.home.score, 10) > parseInt(game.away.score, 10) ? 'highlight':''}
```

And yes, you can define another variable. Just put it before `return`:

```
render: function() {
    var gameList = this.props.data.map(function(game) {
        var classNameExt = parseInt(game.home.score, 10) > parseInt(game.away.score, 10) ? 'highlight':'';
        return (
            <li key={game.id} className="list-group-item">
                    {game.home_team_name}
                    <span className={'pull-right ' + classNameExt}>{game.home.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.away_team_name}
                    <span className={'pull-right ' + classNameExt}>{game.away.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.status.status}
            </li>   
        );
    });
```

Or to highlight only the winner:

```
render: function() {
    var gameList = this.props.data.map(function(game) {
        return (
            <li key={game.id} className="list-group-item">
                    {game.home_team_name}
                    <span className={'pull-right ' + (parseInt(game.home.score, 10) > parseInt(game.away.score, 10) ? 'highlight':'')}>{game.home.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.away_team_name}
                    <span className={'pull-right ' + (parseInt(game.home.score, 10) < parseInt(game.away.score, 10) ? 'highlight':'')}>{game.away.score}</span> <br />
                    {game.status.status}
            </li>   
        );
    });
```

Comment: Just tried this method with no luck. Do I have to append it to the className?

Comment: Not sure what type your data is, please try with parseInt for comparison @Simon

Comment: You have to remove the quotes from the className properties that have a statement.

Comment: Great this works! I'm trying to highlight the one that is the largest. I see my condition only highlights if the home score is greater than the away score. How would I proceed to highlight just the largest? Would ternary still be ideal?

Comment: What do you mean with "just the largest" ? Just the winning team's score? @Simon

Comment: Yes, that is correct only the winning team's score. For instance if the home score is the winner, only the section with the home team and home score will be highlighted and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Michael